# Parsing JSON value with SwiftyJSON (and Alamofire)

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I am trying to parse a single value from a REST web service that I am testing.
I understand how to make the call and I see the JSON response in the Output window.

```
let request = Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://IP:PORT/jsonTest", parameters: ["s": "Ping?"])
        .responseJSON{(_,_,data,_) in             
            var json = JSON(data!)                
            println(json)
```

The Console Output shows me:

```
{"NewDataSet":[
    {"Table1":[
        {"Column-A":"FirstA",
         "Column-B":"FirstB"
        },
        {"Column-A":"SecondA",
         "Column-B":"SecondB"
        },
        {"Column-A":"ThirdA",
        "Column-B":"ThirdB"
        }
    ]}
]}
```

What I would like to do now, is to display only the first value from Column-A - which in this example would be "FirstA".

I've been trying to use a code like this, but so far I am not getting anywhere...

```
println(json[0][0]["Column-A"].stringValue)
```

Any pointers much appreciated!

Comment: You have an object containing an entry named "NewDataSet".  That entry is an array containing objects.  The first element of the array contains an object with an element named "Tabel1".  That element is an array.  The first element of the array is an object, containing an element named "Column-A".  You seem to have ignored all the objects other than the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
json["NewDataSet"][0]["Table1"][0]["Column-A"].stringValue
```

This is what you want. This is because your json starts with a dictionary and is formatted as dictionary>array>dictionary>array>dictionary. Note that json dictionaries are noted by { : , : } while arrays are noted as [ , ].